# convert data c# from string format yyyymmdd to ddmmyy

Tags: arrays, string, datetime

How to convert data c# from string format yyyymmdd to ddmmyy

I have a similar string (20180403) and I would like to get this (030418)

How I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var ddMMyyString = DateTime.ParseExact(yyyyMMddString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("ddMMyy")`

See:

- [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)
- [`DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_)